# I'm having trouble rendering my data from Firebase in React-Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

The aim is to display a list of posts in a FlatList. I've created a custom 'Post' component to hold each of the variables. I've run the database URL through Postman and the data was retrieved. I'm wondering if there is an issue with my code or React Native itself?

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.61.5

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {FlatList, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import Post from './Post';
import Firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/database';
import {firebaseConfig} from './configFirebase';

export default class Posts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    !Firebase.apps.length
      ? Firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig.firebase)
      : Firebase.app();

    this.state = {
      postList: [],
    };
  }

  getPostData() {
    let ref = Firebase.database().ref('/posts');
    ref.on('value', snapshot => {
      const state = snapshot.val();
      this.setState(state);
    });
    console.log('DATA RETRIEVED');
  }

  getItemCount() {
    Firebase.database()
      .ref('/posts')
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        const postCount = snapshot.key.length;
        this.setState({postCount});
      });
  }

  renderItem() {
    const post = this.state;
    return (
      <Post
        key={post.key}
        heading={post.heading}
        description={post.description}
        location={post.location}
      />
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPostData();
    this.getItemCount();
    this.renderItem();
  }

  render() {
    const {postList} = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {postList.map(post => (
          <FlatList
            keyExtractor={post.id}
            data={this.state.postList}
            getItem={this.renderItem}
            getItemCount={this.getItemCount}
          />
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#2bb76e',
    flex: 1,
  },
  txtInput: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 5,
    padding: 5,
    borderWidth: 2,
    fontSize: 20,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'snow',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There were quite a few things that I think were wrong with the code (at least as far as my understanding of how react native and firebase work!)

I've added a lot of comments. Hope this makes sense:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import Post from './Post';
import Firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/database';
import { firebaseConfig } from './configFirebase';

export default class Posts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    !Firebase.apps.length ? Firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig.firebase) : Firebase.app();

    this.state = {
      postList: []
    };
  }

  // moved componentDidMount to top as per convention
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPostData();
    // this.getItemCount(); // I'm pretty sure you don't need this
    // this.renderItem(); // this doesn't belong here
  }

  // use arrow function so references to 'this' are bound to the component
  getPostData = () => {
    const ref = Firebase.database().ref('/posts'); // use const. It doesn't change.
    ref.on('value', snapshot => {
      console.log('DATA RETRIEVED'); // move inside the callback, so only triggers if you do actually retrieve data
      const postsObj = snapshot.val();

      if (!postsObj) return console.warn('No data from firebase');

      const postsArr = Object.values(postsObj);

      this.setState({postList: postsArr}); 
   });
  };

  // I don't think you need getItemCount...

  // getItemCount() {
  //   Firebase.database().ref('/posts').on('value', snapshot => {
  //     const postCount = snapshot.key.length;
  //     this.setState({ postCount });
  //   });
  // }

  renderItem({ item: post, index }) {
    return (
      <Post
        key={index} // changed this to index, because your post objects don't have keys. But if you can add unique keys then that will be better!
        heading={post.heading}
        description={post.description}
        location={post.location}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {/* Cleaned up FlatList... I think you got confused here */}
        <FlatList
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()} // syntax was wrong. Fixed.
          data={this.state.postList}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#2bb76e',
    flex: 1
  },
  txtInput: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 5,
    padding: 5,
    borderWidth: 2,
    fontSize: 20,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'snow'
  }
});
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210378/discussion-on-answer-by-james-im-having-trouble-rendering-my-data-from-firebase).